# Remove html tags using Regex

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

[image]

Im trying to get rid of the HTML tags, to an extent it works, but not all the tags are removed. But the below mentioned tags aren't gone

```
print('NOT DEALT WITH:')
for body in not_dealt_with_list:
#p = re.compile(r'<.*?[\\t\\n\\r\\s]*?.*?>')
    print(remove_tags(body))
    #print(p.sub('', body))
    #body = re.sub()

def remove_tags(content):
parser = lxml.html.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True, 
remove_blank_text=True)
document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(content, parser)
return document.text_content()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like what you're trying to remove is embedded into a html comment (because it doesn't look like html there). Html comments start with  and that's what you have to search for.

Try this regex to search for everything inside a comment to replace it afterwards over multiple lines

```
<!--(.|\n)*?-->
```

Let me know how it works out!